# A good book in hyperbolic geometry with synthetic approach?

Tags: book-recommendation, hyperbolic-geometry

Is there a good book in hyperbolic geometry with synthetic approach ? Maybe in the style of Spivak's "Calculus".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geometry: Euclid and Beyond](http://www.springer.com/cn/book/9780387986500) seems like a reasonable first choice, although it also has some extra bits that require a bit of abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1):

there is some extra material in the fourth edition of Marvin Greenberg's book, *Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries.*. I found a bunch of material in Russian and Ukrainian from the 1930's to the 1950's for an article I published. Anyway, both got interested, Hartshorne proved a theorem of Mordukhai-Boltovskoi in his own way, and Marvin put that into the book. Found the pages, announced on pages 527-528, detail in Appendix B, part 1, pages 571-588.  Here is a [LINK](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/old-and-new-results-in-the-foundations-of-elementary-plane-euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometries) to a review of an article by Marvin that won an award, you can download the article from there.

Comment: Actually I know Ukrainian and Russian so what material were you talking about ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош see the references in http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf   My friend Dmitry actually wrote out a translation of a short piece by Nestorovich in my references. For the longer M-B articles, he read translations over the telephone of the parts I saw were important. There were also some full length books, Dmitry just gave me a sense of the contents.